# Angular test - ng2-datetime: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dates' of undefined

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-cli, ng2-datetime

I'm using Angular-cli and also this library: [ng2-datetime](https://github.com/nkalinov/ng2-datetime).

I have [posted a comment](https://github.com/nkalinov/ng2-datetime/issues/66#issuecomment-311602744) pointing out this issue, but wanted to try my luck on SO aswell...

**Issue:**

When executing the `ng-test` command, I'm getting the following error message:

> Chrome 59.0.3071 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'dates' of undefined   at
>   webpack:///~/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js:1:0
>   <- src/test.ts:124808
>
> Chrome 59.0.3071 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'dates' of undefined   at
>   webpack:///~/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js:1:0
>   <- src/test.ts:124808

Highlighted:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dates' of undefined**

**at webpack:///~/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js:1:0 <- src/test.ts:124808**

I'm actually importing these scripts in the module of the components where is going to be used, like this:

```
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.de.min.js';
import 'bootstrap-datepicker/dist/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.es.min.js';
```

I have tried multiple approaches, like adding to `karma.conf.js` the jquery script:

```
files: [
            {pattern: './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', watched: true},
            {pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false}
        ],
```

I'm really stuck with this one, but I believe it may be a common issue with jQuery based libraries used in Angular.

Thanks for the help, if you need any aditional information just let me know, I'll provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue for this, it was so simple!

I just needed to add a line to **`karma.conf.js`**:

```
{pattern: './node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js', watched: false},
```

My final `files` array within this file is like this:

```
files: [
    {pattern: './node_modules/jquery-ui-npm/jquery-ui.min.js', watched: false},
    {pattern: './node_modules/bootstrap-datepicker/dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js', watched: false},
    {pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false}
],
```